# WiFi and Bluetooth not working on android-x86_64-8.1-r1

Tags: wi-fi, bluetooth, android-x86

I have install **Android (android-x86_64-8.1-r1)** on my HP Pavilion G4 Notebook PC. For few months, it worked very well (except Bluetooth). But now it can't see Wi-Fis around me and the Bluetooth didn't worked from the installation. I have tried a previous version (android-x86_64-7.1-r1) and PhoenixOS (based on Android-x86) but the same problem. Is there any solutions?

Comment: A log would help if you could throw the command `adb logcat -v long` and paste it to pastbin or some other such site and then edit your question with the link.

Comment: @BoLawson How can I throw the command? I have tried to executing ```adb logcat -v long``` on terminal emulator. But it show a error message ```/system/bin/sh: adb: not fonud```

Comment: From a terminal emulator you are throwing commands from a shell. Soo, just remove the adb part and only throw `logcat -v long`. All should be good and you can keep on trucking.